# Find zero values from a file

Tags: shell

I need to find whether any line of my file has a value of 0 in the fifth column.  The values in this column are all numbers:

```
cat /home/vsrchops/Usrlogin_1.csv | awk '{print $5}'
8
8
1
4
2
8
23
61
473
1465
1771
2200
```

I tried this command:

```
cat /home/vsrchops/Usrlogin_1.csv | awk '{print $5}' | grep 0
```

But it matches all lines *containing* 0, rather than those that are *exactly* 0:

```
2200
```

How do I find values that are exactly zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `cat` command is unnecessary, since we can use `<` to redirect AWK's input to read from the file.

We could modify the `grep` command to match the start and end of line like this:

```
awk '{print $5}' </home/vsrchops/Usrlogin_1.csv | grep '^0$'
```

Here, `^` matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end of line.

Or we can use `grep` options to match the whole line:

```
awk '{print $5}' </home/vsrchops/Usrlogin_1.csv | grep -Fx 0
```

Either of these will match only those lines that are exactly 0.

---

Alternatively, we could avoid creating the `grep` process, and do the matching entirely within AWK:

```
awk '$5 ~ /^0$/ {print $5}' </home/vsrchops/Usrlogin_1.csv
```

That's probably the simplest and most efficient solution.

Comment: Why not awk only?

Comment: The example given in the question was using grep, so it makes sense to show how to achieve the goal with grep. I find it easier to read / understand the line using grep but that's just me. No doubt many other ways to do this as well.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean now. Why use cat and a pipe. 

awk '$5~/^0$/{print $5}' /home/vsrchops/Usrlogin_1.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
jot -w 'f1 f2 f3 f4 %d f6' 7 -10 - 5 | gtee >( gcat -b >&2) |
```

---

```
     1  f1 f2 f3 f4 -10 f6
     2  f1 f2 f3 f4 -5 f6
     3  f1 f2 f3 f4 0 f6
     4  f1 f2 f3 f4 5 f6
     5  f1 f2 f3 f4 10 f6
     6  f1 f2 f3 f4 15 f6
     7  f1 f2 f3 f4 20 f6
```

---

```
mawk '_!!_ == ($!NF = $5)'
nawk '_!!_ == ($+_ = $5)'
gawk '_!!_ == ($_ = $5)'
```

---

```
     1  0
```

`_!!_` is actually a string concat of empty string `_` with numeric zero (`!!_`) to form string-zero (`"0"`)

This approach fails for scenarios like `$5 == "00"` `$5 == "+0"`

Answer (score 0):

Little shorter:

```
awk '$5==0{print $5}' /home/vsrchops/Usrlogin_1.csv
```

(Matches values that are `0`, e. g. `0` or `00`)

Answer (score -1):

How about an if statement in the AWK?

```
echo "1;2;\n2;0;\n5;00;" | awk -F\; '{ if ( $2 == "0" ) {print $2} }'
```

Comment: Please share the command. will try